# Sorting a list according to the position of elements

Tags: list-manipulation, sorting

I have a list of elements, which I want to sort according to the even/odd numbered positions of elements. Basically creating two lists out of one, respectively having elements placed at even/odd positions in the original list.

For example, A = {a, b, c, d, e, f}; should split into A1 = {a, c, e} and A2 = {b, d, f}.

Will appreciate any help.

Comment: `{A1, A2} = Transpose@Partition[A, 2]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
A1 = A[[;; ;; 2]];
A2 = A[[2 ;; ;; 2]];
```